# How save file after processing in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new in python. I started to make a script for processing HTML files with `Beautiful Soup`. Everything is processing correctly, but I would now like to save the article in a new folder called `nowe` instead of printing it. I need to get all of the articles into the same folder after processing, or make a single CSV file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os, os.path


path = '/home/darek/Dokumenty/pliki/'
path_out = '/home/darek/Dokumenty/pliki/nowe'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.html',)):
    f = filename
    tresc = open(f)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tresc, 'html.parser') 
    article = soup.find('div',class_='post')
    tagi = soup.find('div', class_='ph_social_share_box ph_social_share_box_bottom')

    fout = open( +filename, "w")
    fout.close()

print(article)
```

My error log:

```
File "/home/darek/Dokumenty/parser.py", line 21, in <module>
    fout = open( +filename, "w")

TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

That's  works for print

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import glob
    import os, os.path

```
path = '/home/darek/Dokumenty/pliki/'
path_out = '/home/darek/Dokumenty/pliki/nowe'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.html',)):
    f = filename
    content = open(f)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser') 
    article = soup.find('div',class_='post')
    tags = soup.find('div', class_='ph_social_share_box ph_social_share_box_bottom')


print(article)
```

Thats works i can't write to file idea?

Comment: `filename` is a string.  What are you trying to express with `+filename`?  The Python interpreter can't understand, either.

Comment: It appears that you need to work through a tutorial on file handling.  Inside a loop, your code opens `filename` and immediately closes it, without doing anything to the file.

Comment: I would open folder whith html files after parsing and save in another. Is my first program ever i suposed mistakes. At this moment whithour last line fout they print result to screan. How change that for save for files.

Comment: You are trying to program several steps beyond your current ability.  Again, please work through the appropriate tutorials to increase your ability.  Stack Overflow is an archive of useful question-answer postings, *not* a general help site.

Comment: If you search for "Python file tutorial", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: I watched a lot but everythime is for single txt file or single command is not example for 500 html files in subcategories. I know html is not same for python like *txt. I need smth like load from here for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.html',)): and save in new folder + 1 or some new name in folder

Comment: You're confusing handling a single file with your looping logic.  Tutorials teach you individual techniques, and you still need to come up to speed on handling a single file.  Once you have that much, you wrap it in a loop to handle many files in order.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "+" in this line:
`fout = open( +filename, "w")`

The "w" means: "open the file in write mode".
If you add a "+" to it, like "w+", it will start writing to the file from the start when it is opened. So the line should be

`fout = open(filename, "w+")`

Comment: i give edit for mine file that's don' works. same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change this block of code:

```
fout = open( +filename, "w")
fout.close()
```

To be this:

```
fout = open( filename, "w")
fout.write(article) # I assume here that article is what you want to be writing
fout.close()

tresc.close() # You never closed this, so it was a memory leak
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're trying to say.